# Stealing Commercial Controls

Tags: discussion

This morning I flagged three answers to a single [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447274/theres-a-yellow-colour-text-called-demo-in-my-daypilot-calendar-control-how-to), each of which describes how to steal a commercial control. Since none of the other options seemed appropriate, I selected *"Other (needs moderator attention)"*.

These flags have been declined with the following reason:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Does StackExchange support stealing other people's work?
If not, how do I report these answers?

Answer (score 11):

This is a tricky area for us. Enforcing license violations for commercial components is a bit outside of our scope, and moderators generally don't handle this. We typically direct people to contact Stack Exchange with a formal DMCA takedown request. We've seen enough bogus claims of copyright violation and claims against grey-area uses (phone jailbreaking, security research, etc.) that we'd rather have the legal team at SE deal with something signed under threat of perjury.

Your flags on the answers themselves were declined because the moderator involved didn't want to delete legitimate answers, even if they were directed towards helping someone work around a commercial license. I'd have probably done so myself, just looking at the answers by themselves.

However, I took a look at that question and thought it was of poor quality overall, so I deleted the whole thing. It's not worth the effort to defend that.

Comment: Thanks. I can see your point, but I still think that answers which are obviously describing how to remove or circumvent deliberate limitations of un-licensed copies of commercial products shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: You can think that, but if you're not the copyright holder of the material in question you don't have standing to do anything about it.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - Also, people can be mistaken about what constitutes a license violation, legal requirements differ in various territories, and, well, people have outright lied to us about something being illegal. You'd be surprised at the number of answers that have been flagged by those with competing answers in an attempt to fool us and get us to delete their competitors.

Comment: In this particular case: if you don't pay for the control in question, it displays "demo" in the top-left corner *(not an unreasonable "limitation" IMO)*; all three answers explained how to hide the "demo" text; and I hadn't posted a competing answer because I felt that the premise of the question was flawed. :)

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Are you saying that if Dan Letecky had reported the answers, they would have been deleted?